# How to insert data underneath a specific column in csv file python

Tags: python, csv

I have this code:

```
  def _download_url(url):
    response = None
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

        content_bytes=response.read()
        content_string=content_bytes.decode(encoding='utf-8')

        data = io.StringIO(content_string)
        mycsv=csv.reader(data)
        mycsv = csv.DictReader(data)

        print('{:<11} {:<8} {:<12} {:<12}'.format('Date', 'Close', 'Indicator', 'Signal'))
        for row in mycsv:

            print('{:<11} {:<8}'.format(row['Date'], row['Adj Close']))
```

How do I create a code so I am able to INSERT data UNDERNEATH the Indicator/Signal column?
I want to grab the data from the "close" column and use that list of numbers to find the average and print it out underneath the indicator column. And then use the results in indicator and do something with it underneath the signal column.

--edit-- this is how it looks like when I run it

```
Date        Close    Indicator    Signal      
2012-11-30  698.37   
2012-11-29  691.89  
2012-11-28  683.67  
2012-11-27  670.71  
2012-11-26  661.15  
2012-11-23  667.97
```

However, I want it to look like

```
Date        Close    Indicator    Signal      
2012-11-30  698.37     0
2012-11-29  691.89  -put data here-
2012-11-28  683.67  -another data-
2012-11-27  670.71  -etc-
2012-11-26  661.15  
2012-11-23  667.97
```

I want to grab data from the second column (close) and use those numbers to calculate the average

Comment: Would it be possible to show what your input data looks like and what you want the output to look like - with illustrative data. As using the 'close' column average for 'indicator' is confusing, for me at least, as what happen on the next row?

Comment: i edited in order to show what I want thanks

Answer (score 0):

Still no understanding what the OP wants as the following would

> INSERT data UNDERNEATH the Indicator/Signal column
>   but I can't believe that's what the OP wants.

So by putting `calculated_indicator` and `calculated_signal` in we can then determine if these functions work on rows or the complete set of rows.

```
def calculated_indicator(row):
     return 0

def calculated_signal(row):
     return 0

def _download_url(url):
    response = None
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

        content_bytes=response.read()
        content_string=content_bytes.decode(encoding='utf-8')

        data = io.StringIO(content_string)
        mycsv=csv.reader(data)
        mycsv = csv.DictReader(data)

        print('{:<11} {:<8} {:<12} {:<12}'.format('Date', 'Close', 'Indicator', 'Signal'))
        for row in mycsv:

            print('{:<11} {:<8}'.format(row['Date'], row['Adj Close'], calculated_indicator(row), calculated_signal(row)))
```